# App Crashes when enter OnDataChange FireBase Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap, firebase

I'm getting an error when I try to Cast A DataSnapshot as a Hashmap.

```
private void ponerCasoEnLista(){



        final ArrayList<DatosCaso> datos = new ArrayList<>();
        RUTA_DB.child("casos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                HashMap<String, String> casos = (HashMap<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
                for (Object caso : casos.values()) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> casoMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) caso;
                    DatosCaso nuevosdatos = new DatosCaso((String) casoMap.get("nombre"), (String) casoMap.get("color"));
                    datos.add(nuevosdatos);
                    Log.d("NUEVOCASO", "Agrego caso al array");

                   /* if (!userInfoList.contains(userNumber)) {
                        String name = (String) userMap.remove("username");
                        String pic = (String) userMap.remove("profile_picture");
                        UserInfo info = new UserInfo(userNumber, name, pic);
                        userInfoList.add(info);
                    }*/
                }
                // thread executing here can get info from database and make subsequent call
                Collections.addAll(datos);
                ponerCasoEnListview(datos);
            }
```

I'm getting this:

10-16 00:30:22.951  15066-15066/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gasti.escribocaso1510, PID: 15066
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
            at com.example.gasti.escribocaso1510.ActividadPrincipal$2.onDataChange(ActividadPrincipal.java:109)

In this line after OnDataChange:

```
HashMap<String, String> casos = (HashMap<String, String>) snapshot.getValue();
```

Comment: Likely answer below. if that's not it, **edit** your question to include a snippet of the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cast to a HashMap, simply use

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {   Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.e("***", "onDataChange -> " + objectMap.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to be sure without seeing your data structure, but I'm guessing that `casos` is a list of multiple `caso` objects.

In that case:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (Object caso : casos.values()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> casoMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) caso;
        DatosCaso nuevosdatos = new DatosCaso((String) casoMap.get("nombre"), (String) casoMap.get("color"));
```

You should seriously consider creating a JavaBean object for DatosCaso:

```
public class DatosCaso {
  String nombre;
  String color;
  public DatosCaso() {}
  public String getNombre() { return nombre; }
  public String getColor() { return color; }
}
```

This allows you to bypass the HashMap:

```
DatosCaso nuevosdatos = caso.getValue(DatosCaso.class);
```